# How to POST to PHP when dragging items from one div to another?

Tags: javascript, php, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have two Parent divs with dynamic children divs and now I would like to implement POST to PHP when dropping from one side to the other (both ways).

**My Javascript:**

```
    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        console.log('drag', ev.target.id);
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        console.log('drop', ev.dataTransfer.getData("text"));
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
```

**HTML with PHP data:**

```
<fieldset id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <legend style="color:cadetblue; border:white; width:auto; font:bold">Vacant parking spots</legend>
    <?php
    foreach ($sql_get_vacant_spots_results_ as $row) { ?>
        <div id="<?php echo $row; ?>" style="float: left; width: 120px;height: 80px;padding: 10px;border-radius: 20px;margin: 10px;background-color: cadetblue;" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="88" height="31">
            <labled style="color: white; font:bold; font-size:large;"><?php echo 'Spot: ' . $row['spot_no'] . ' Gate: ' . $row['parking_gate_id'] ?></label>
        </div>
    <?php }
     ?>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <legend style="color:cadetblue; border:white; width:auto; font:bold">Current parking spots of the customer</legend>
    <?php
    foreach ($arr_users as $user) { ?>
        <div id="<?php echo $user ?>" style="float: left; width: 120px;height: 80px;padding: 10px;border-radius: 20px;margin: 10px;background-color: cadetblue;" draggable="true" width="88" height="31">
            <labled style="color: white; font:bold; font-size:large;"><?php echo 'Spot: ' . $user['spot_id'] . ' Gate: ' .  $user['gate_id'] ?></label>
        </div>
    <?php
    } ?>
</fieldset>
```

Now, the main problem is that I MUST set an Array as ID to the children divs because there is no auto-incremented (unique id) of the elements I am fetching from the database. As you can see I am already attaching the entire arrays as id `id="<?php echo $user ?>"` and `id="<?php echo $row; ?>"`.

Comment: why if you need id don't use `$row['id']`

Comment: @Simone Rossaini: Probably because there aint one: *..because there is no auto-incremented (unique id) of the elements..*

Comment: if exist a foreach he can 'create' it use counter no? for example if id is '1', he can use '1-1' so will be unique, if coming another '1' simple will '2-1'

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I have already tried with the $counter++ but as Lain is saying, how database is going to recognize that? Therefore I must post the entire array to PHP and then I will take care of the loop in PHP.

Comment: I hadn't really thought about it. out of curiosity why hasn't a unique id been implemented in the database?

Comment: You could add different attributes.. like `<div id="<?=$row;?>" data-x="<?=$attributeX;?>"  data-y="<?=$attributeY;?>" data-z="<?=$attributeZ;?>"`. Depending on your structure. Then you can access those using [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) or `setAttribute()`.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini because I am fetching from a relational table thus doesn't have any unique single id, I actually have a composite key of three fields.

Comment: @Lain I have never used those, I don't really understand them. Please enlighten me!

Comment: [There you go](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset). Just custom attributes which you can use however you see fit, as long as they start with `data-`.

Comment: @Lain I tried that but its print "DomStringmap {}" . ` const el = document.querySelector("[id]"); console.log('drop', el.dataset);` The Div:  `data-x="<?php echo $arr_users[0]['customer_id']; ?>" `

Comment: @dontdownvoteme: `console.log('drop', el.dataset.x)`.

Comment: @Lain I did that but it prints `undefined`

Comment: @Lain I think its the way I am getting the element by id `const el = document.querySelector("[id]");`. I guess its not finding by `id`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, just was too much for a comment.

### Accessing [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset)

```js
//REM: Sample structure with three keys
var Rows = [
  {key1: 'key1a', key2: 'key2a', key3: 'key3a'},
  {key1: 'key1b', key2: 'key2b', key3: 'key3b'},
  {key1: 'key1c', key2: 'key2c', key3: 'key3c'}
];

//REM: Having no php here
Rows.forEach(function(item){
  document.body.innerHTML += "<div data-x='" + item.key1 + "' onclick = 'alert(this.dataset.x)'>" + JSON.stringify(item) + "</div>"
});
```

### Using everything as JSON

```js
//REM: Sample structure with three keys
var Rows = [
  {key1: 'key1a', key2: 'key2a', key3: 'key3a'},
  {key1: 'key1b', key2: 'key2b', key3: 'key3b'},
  {key1: 'key1c', key2: 'key2c', key3: 'key3c'}
];

//REM: Having no php here
Rows.forEach(function(item){
  document.body.innerHTML += "<div data-json='" + JSON.stringify(item) + "' onclick = 'alert(JSON.parse(this.dataset.json).key1)'>" + JSON.stringify(item) + "</div>"
});
```

We would need your actual structure for a more specific suggestion.

Comment: I have tried this way: `const el = document.querySelector('#' +ev.dataTransfer.getData("text"));` and yet it throws this error "Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#33' is not a valid selector." . So as you can see it DOES find the id but doesn't recognize it as valid selector.

Comment: `id` shall not start with numbers. Use a prefix or `getElementById()`.

Comment: Can you give a sample of your rows? Like three rows?